# Best way of calculating a mathematical value using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

All user scores are stored in the following collection:

```
var scoreSchema = new Schema({
  userId: String,
  totalPredictions: Number, 
  wins: Number,
  pending: Number,
  accuracy: Number
});
```

Here accuracy is defined as

```
accuracy = wins * 100 / (totalPredictions - pending)
```

What I would like to do is update the accuracy field everytime an update is made to the document

As per mongoose, we can use schema.pre('save'.. method.

However that does not get called on findOneAndUpdate which is a concern.

How else can i maintain the validity of this field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals).

For example,

```
scoreSchema.virtual("accuracy").get(function(){
    return this.wins * 100 / (this.totalPredictions - pending);
});
```

Before doing this, you may need to enable virtuals:

```
var scoreSchema = new Schema({
  userId: String,
  totalPredictions: Number, 
  wins: Number,
  pending: Number,
  accuracy: Number
},{
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});
```

Comment: by default when I do a Model.find .. the virual attributes are not returned.. hence this does not help

Comment: @SMV Edited, try this.